# Can I not remove the return key on the keyboard? Or at least change its text to "Set"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am creating a sign up page for my iphone app and am having some problems making the way the input views work for the different kinds of fields consistent. The fields are listed as cells in a table view and the editing is supposed to take place directly in the table by having appropriate input views sliding up from the bottom.

Let me focus on only two of the fields here, namely the *username* field and the *birthday* field: for the username field it makes sense to have an ASCII capable keyboard sliding up when the user presses the field whereas a date picker seems more useful in the birthday field case.

For both the keyboard and the date picker the **cancel** button could be located in a tool bar just above the input view. But what about the **set** button? If I put that in the toolbar as well I need the return key in the keyboard to go away! But that is not possible is it?

If the return key cannot be removed then I might have to live with the set button in the toolbar only in the birthday case and then use the return key as the set button in the username case - but can I then at least change the text on the return key to "Set"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible* to hide the "Return" key.

It is not possible to set the string to "Set" either, but could use [the `.returnKeyType`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInputTraits/returnKeyType) property to change it to a [limited set of strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIReturnKeyType).

```
theTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

<sub>(* Well you could put an opaque UIView directly above it but it's a very bad practice and generally breaks if the user chooses a different input method)</sub>