# How to hide the return key on IOS keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, key, return

With my UITextField, my users can do several things for validate. I use the inputAccessoryView  for that. Now I want  hide the return key on keyboard.

Is this possible ? how ?

Comment: [No it's not possible* to hide the "Return" key.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5835601/1280373)

Answer (score 5):

You can replace return key with # and @ keys by setting keyboardType to UIKeyboardTypeTwitter on your UITextField.

Comment: Agreed. Easiest solution I found thanks to borisgolovnev. Other solutions are far more complex and require things like detecting when the keyboard appears, finding the keyboard subview and then manipulating it, or creating a custom keyboard

Comment: reloadInputViews() seems to be a better solution here - resolves a potential issue with graphical glitches

Answer (score 0):

`reloadInputViews()` - Updates the custom input and accessory views when the object is the first responder.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621110-reloadinputviews